# Passar vários dados para um input, atraves de um select

Tags: php, javascript

Estou tentando passar *vários* dados para um *input*, tinha quase ideia de que seria uma *textarea* pela quantidade mas seria outro *select* ? Esta assim:

[image: Imagem com 1 somente]

Estou tentando para que fique assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se alguém puder da uma dica ficarei grato. Segue o código:

```js
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function passar(){ 
var valorA = document.getElementById("valorA"); 
var nome = document.getElementById("nome"); 
nome.value = valorA.value; 
}; 
</script>
```

```html
<select name="valorA" id="valorA" size="3" multiple>
  <option value="Gezer">Gezer</option> 
  <option value="João" selected>João</option>
  <option value="Marcos">Marcos</option>
</select>
 
<button type="button" onclick="passar();"> passar valores </button> 

Nome:<input type="text" id="nome" size="10"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se é a melhor implementação, mais você pode resolver seu problema alterando sua função assim:

```
function passar() {
   var valorA = document.getElementById("valorA");
   var nome = document.getElementById("nome");

   for(var i = 0; i <= valorA.options.length; i++) { //itero em cada option
     nome.value += (valorA.options[i].value + '\n'); //seto o (value|text) no textarea com uma quebra de linha
   }    
};
```

Segue [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/rnrcgxm8/) :)

E para passar o `option` selecionado, você pode fazer simplesmente assim:

```
function passar() {
    var valorA = document.getElementById("valorA");
    var nome = document.getElementById("nome");

    nome.value += (valorA.value + '\n'); //Acessa diretamente o value do select que já é o elemento selecionado
};
```

Segue o [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/rnrcgxm8/1/) :)

Comment: hum vi que esta acrescentando todos como posso um por um selecionado um de cada vez ou poderia fazer em php?

Comment: para passar um de cada vez você pode fazer assim [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/rnrcgxm8/1/) vou atualizar no post :) a solução acima é com javascript, php já foge da minha area de conhecimento hehe

Comment: mano vc me ajudou muito estava fazendo em php mas desiste, ate funcionou mas fica melhor para mim assim menos código muito obrigado mesmo. abençoado seja. vou adaptar para outra cosia agora kkk